# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'retrieve' #1195

Tags: solidity, python, brownie

i'm getting this error in simple storage deploy script

here is the deploy.py code

```
from brownie import accounts, config, SimpleStorage

def deploy_simple_storage():
    account = accounts[0]
    # account = accounts.add(config["wallets"]["rahool_key"])
    simple_storage = SimpleStorage.deploy({"from":account}). tx.wait(1)
    stored_value =simple_storage.retrieve()
    print(stored_value)
    


def main():
    deploy_simple_storage()
```

The terminal when I run deploy.py

```
Transaction sent: 0x012c6bde69d8233b74e5a3524b058b565bb514793a8d53508139291844a39b98
  Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 12000000   Nonce: 0
  SimpleStorage.constructor confirmed   Block: 1   Gas used: 338038 (2.82%)
  SimpleStorage deployed at: 0x3194cBDC3dbcd3E11a07892e7bA5c3394048Cc87

  SimpleStorage.constructor confirmed   Block: 1   Gas used: 338038 (2.82%)
  SimpleStorage deployed at: 0x3194cBDC3dbcd3E11a07892e7bA5c3394048Cc87

  File "C:\Users\dhaka\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "C:\Users\dhaka\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 103, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File "/1.Coding/Python/brownie_simple_storage/scripts/deploy.py", line 15, in main
    deploy_simple_storage()
  File "/1.Coding/Python/brownie_simple_storage/scripts/deploy.py", line 7, in deploy_simple_storage
    stored_value =simple_storage.retrieve()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'retrieve'
Terminating local RPC client...
```

Answer (score 0):

you actually don't need a wait here.
your code should be as below

```
from brownie import accounts, config, SimpleStorage

def deploy_simple_storage():
    account = accounts[0]
    # account = accounts.add(config["wallets"]["rahool_key"])
    simple_storage = SimpleStorage.deploy({"from":account})
    stored_value = simple_storage.retrieve()
    print(stored_value)

def main():
    deploy_simple_storage()
```

Comment: yes i removed it later and it worked, though i dont know why.
it was just hit and trial :)

Comment: i still don't  understand it
if i add tx.wait(1) the error above is solved but if i dont add it then i get brownie.exceptions.RPCRequestError: Web3 is not connected.

Comment: as per https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-py/issues/173#issuecomment-941525143 this error occurs when you don't wait for all transactions to complete

Answer (score 0):

Rahool, waiting your transaction should be `simple_storage.wait(1)` on next line and remove `. tx.wait(1)`

Comment: There's no tx object so it will error out anyway.

Comment: I noticed that,, later resolved it using time.sleep(1)